# What does '/=' operator mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this looking at the source for some physics animations in JavaScript found [here on github](https://github.com/iamralpht/iamralpht.github.io/blob/master/physics/androidwear.js#L107) where he's written this

```
if (this._position < 0) this._position /= 3;
```

A quick Google yielded nothing, anyone know?

Comment: [Shorthand division operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Division_assignment)

Comment: Called a 'Division/Assignment Operator': It does a divide then assigns the value.  Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: so this means "if the position is less than zero, make position equal to position divided by three"...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The operator is [shorthand division operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Division_assignment). It is equivalent to

```
this.position = this.position / 3;
```

The division will be performed first and then the result will be assigned to the dividend.

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Division_assignment)

> The division assignment operator divides a variable by the value of the right operand and assigns the result to the variable.

Comment: nice! okay that makes sense, not clear as to why he's doing it in that method, but I suppose thats another question.

Comment: @pushplaybang The comments in the source file explain why:  // If the finger is dragging the menu in a direction it won't go then
        // make the movement less effective.

Answer (score 1):

It's the division equivalent of `+=` or `-=`

Answer (score 1):

This is a division asignment operator:
This performs the following operation:
Ex:

```
var x=10,y=2;
x=x/y;
/*
which is equivalent to x/=y;
and returns 5
*/
```